# CSS gradient issue, only works in Firefox and Safari

Tags: linear-gradients, css

I've made a (very beautiful in my case) half transparent gradient background, but I can only make it working in Firefox and Safari.

**Firefox:**

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 500px) repeat fixed 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The issue now is that in all other browsers **IE10, Chrome and Opera**, *the last rgba(0,0,0,0) overlay seems to be ignored*, which causes the gradient kind of shining instead darkened.

**Code for the other browsers:**

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(500px,rgba(0,0,0,0))) repeat fixed 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 500px) repeat fixed 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 500px) repeat fixed 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 500px) repeat fixed 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* IE10+ */
```

How can I get this last dark layer for Chrome, Opera and Internet-Explorer 10?
Do you see something wrong? I guess something wrong with the shorthand code or not possible at all?

Comment: is this inline style?

Comment: @EL no, it's in a .css file `.pagebg{...}`